# What is the best method to assess how "unique" a covariate is?

Tags: psychometrics, predictor, psychology

Essentially, I have about 20 variables (all numerical scores) for different personality measures. I want to measure which is the most unique, ie [edit: *the least predicted by the other variables*.]

Is there a specific statistical test to determine what I'm after? **What's the best method to assess which variable is the least predicted by the other variables?**

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "unique". (Besides, something can't be "the most unique"; something is either unique or it isn't.) Can you be more specific? Do you mean something like "the least predictable by the other 19"?

Comment: Hi, my apologies. "Least predicted by the other 19" is close to what I meant!

Answer (score 4):

A direct approach seems best: for each of the 20 variables in turn, treat it as a dependent variable and try to predict it with the other 19, and compute an estimate of predictive accuracy. For example, you can make a linear regression model with the other 19 and then get the cross-validated root mean square error for predicting the left-out variable. (You should probably use ridge regression or another form of penalized regression rather than OLS, since 19 is kind of a lot unless you have a lot of subjects. If you want to include interaction terms, you will *need* penalization.) The variable with the greatest prediction error is the "most unique" one.

Comment: (+1) Sometimes called "redundancy analysis".

Comment: Does this amount to collinearity detection when using OLS?

Comment: @ssdecontrol This is sort of the reverse. We're looking for variables that are difficult to predict, whereas collinearity is the condition of one variable being highly predictable with one or more others.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple formula for the computation of the not-explained-by-the-other-items variance $u^2_k$ is to compute the inverse $R^{-1}$ of the correlation-matrix $R$, take from this the diagonal $D$ and from this take the reciprocals $1/d_k$ as the values $u^2_k$

*(In some pseudocode it is simply `u2 = 1 / diag(inv(R))`)*